# External WiFi dongle goes to sleep despite power management set to off

Tags: wifi, headless, power-management

I am running a `Raspberry Pi Zero W` as a headless audio player. Since the WiFi-signal in my kitchen is weak, I added an external `TL-WN722N v2` WiFi Dongle which greatly improved signal strength.

My problem now is, that i cannot access the raspberry after a few hours of leaving it idle.
I already tried numerous things. Power management is turned off permanently, iwconfig says: `wlan0: Power Management: off`. I am using the 8188eu driver and have also added various parameters that i found online to prevent sleeping. This is how my config looks like:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/8188eu.conf:
    blacklist r8188eu
    options 8188eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0 rtw_hwpwrp_detect=0 rtw_low_power=0 rtw_ips_mode=1
```

I also created the file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/usbcore.conf:
    options usbcore autosuspend=-1
```

I always have to power cycle it, since I obviously also cannot access it via ssh. I'm running `Raspbian Buster` and also disabled the internal WiFi. The Pi is powered by an external `JustBoom Amp Zero`.

Is there any more energy saving measures that can be disabled?
Or some logs that could be helpful to provide?

**Update:**
According to lsusb the 8188eu driver is actually used:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=8188eu, 480M
```

Comment: IIRC your dongle doesn't use the 8188eu wifi module. You will probably need a different configuration file / modprobe option

Comment: Mhm, looks like it does (updated question with lsusb output)

Comment: As a USB WifI dongle, I suggest researching whether the problem is power savings at the USB level.

Comment: @ChadFarmer i already looked into that but apparently the raspi does not do power save for USB. But thats why i have the `/etc/modprobe.d/usbcore.conf` in there, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by installing another version of the driver.
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/issues/371